# How to set absolute path to $schema in deeply nested jsons

Tags: javascript, node-modules, jsonschema

I have a project where we keep recorded HTML responses as jsons, and they live in directory structure resembling the api paths. I'd like to add $schema property to each json to let IDEs provide some coding assistance / validation.

Because the jsons are nested in many directories, I can't use just one universal relative path to the schema definition. The definition comes from one of the packages in node_modules dir.

I tried `~node_modules` or `~/` but this doesn't work. I expect this will be IDE dependent but maybe someone already stumbled upon such issue and has a solution.

Comment: It indeed depends on your IDE. VSCode for example can be configured like this: https://frontaid.io/blog/json-schema-vscode/ . Can you share a code example on what you did so far? Just adding `$schema` to your data files (the one with the responses) won't work - at least I'm not aware of any standards around this.

Comment: For now we went and used the link to our repo. JetBrains IDEs seem to handle that with no config. I follow the example set by angular.json file. It just has `$schema: './node_modules..../angular.json.schema'` or something like it. But since this is just one file and in static place it is not a problem. If we use relative paths it will be `../../../../../../../` and we'd need to write crawler for that.

Comment: But a friend just tried to use our link in vsc and it worked for him without extra config.